# In mixed content what is the content not enclosed in tags called?

Tags: xml, terminology

As I understand the following is valid xml and called "mixed content" because content both is within tags as well as not within tags:

```
<root>
   free as a bird!
   <tag1>a</tag1>
   <tag2>b</tag2>
</root>
```

But what should I call the content that is not within tags?
I've seen `text` used as a variable name to hold such content but I find it a bit vague.

Answer (score 1):

The terminology varies a bit depending which model you're using, but in tree models of XML (such as DOM and XDM) you've got an element node representing the `root` element, and this has a sequence of child nodes, each of which is either a text node or an element node. In your case the `root` element has five children: a text node containing "free as a bird" with some surrounding whitespace, a `tag1` element, a whitespace-only text node, a `tag2` element, and another whitespace-only text node.